# Через vk.net не могу получить источник фотографии

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api

Пишу бота, переводящего текст+картинку из вк в пост на телегра.ф. Причем ссылка вида `vk.com/photo-цифры_цифры` не подходит, нужен именно источник. Нашел соответственно метод `vk.Photo.GetById()`, заюзал, и начались чудеса. При выводе

```
vk.Photo.GetById(phList, extended: true)[0].ToString
```

выводит вполне себе правильный адрес фото вида `vk.com/photo-цифры_цифры`, то есть все работает. Но при попытке получить например

```
vk.Photo.GetById(phList, extended: true)[0].PhotoSrc,
vk.Photo.GetById(phList, extended: true)[0].BigPhotoSrc,
vk.Photo.GetById(phList, extended: true)[0].Sizes[0]
```

получаю ошибку

> Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

Понять в чем дело решительно не могу, указаний не нашел.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю почему, но срабатывают методы с меньшими размерами картинок. Например, vk.Photo.GetById(phList, extended: true)[0].Photo604 . Так что если кто столкнулся с подобным, используйте это